# I'm getting a "cannot insert null item" in my Create Method but can't understand why?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Here is the code for the Create (POST):

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> Create(
    [Bind(Include = "ProductID,SubscriptionID")] Subscription_Product subscriptionProduct)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.Subscriptions_Products.Add(subscriptionProduct);
        await db.SaveChangesAsync();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    return View(subscriptionProduct);
}
```

I will show some screen shots below that are causing problems. When executing the db.SaveChangesAsync(), I get a null insert error, however stepping through the code I have verified that the values are not null, so I don't understand why this is happening.

As you can see in this image, SubscriptionID and ProductID clearly have non-null values.

[image]

Yet just one line later:

[image]

How the heck is this possible?? In one line it shows a value for SubscriptionID and in the **very next line** it insists that it's null!  Any help would be appreciated. I'll post more methods if you want but didn't want to overcrowd this post with lots of screen shots.

Edit: Someone asked me to do an SQL Server Profiler, so I did that (last image). First I did a successful insert on a known working table, then posted the failed query. They look quite different as for some reason the problem query is only trying to pass in one value. So perhaps this is an issue at the Entity level, but I'm stuck in trying to troubleshoot.

[image]

Comment: Can you run the profiler of your database to capture the query generated from your program and see what is the value being inserted into the database?

Comment: @Lo Thanks. But sorry, how do I do that?

Comment: If you are using mssql, go to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sql-server-profiler/start-sql-server-profiler?view=sql-server-ver15 for other database, a quick google will do

Comment: Okay I did that and I think I discovered the problem but not sure how to fix. I ran the problem query as well as a successful insert on a different table. Too long to paste here but it looks to me that it's something along the lines of INSERT INTO (A,B) Values('A'). So apparently I'm somehow only passing in one value even though the SQL is correct and the prior line shows the inserted object with both variables and their correct values.

Comment: Solved the problem! It had to do with the entity class for that table. It turns out (as I copied that code from another entity class) that I had the following line in the file:

[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)].

When I removed that line and re-migrated, it worked. I have no idea why, but it's good for now.

Comment: Glad it work for you